# Can a debuggable apk file be converted into release apk file without having the source code?

Tags: android

While publishing to play store debuggable apk is not accepted. But source code for the app has accidently being deleted and only a debuggable apk is left, so is there a way by which this apk can be made non-debuggable and published ?

Comment: You could decompile the apk. What comes back won't be quite the same as the source code but java is more amenable to decompiling than most languages

Answer (score 1):

you cant get perfect source code. you must be make application from starting phase.

Answer (score 0):

Dont spend your time for getting source from APK, you have tow solutions:
 1. write your app from the beginig,
 2. try to restore your code from the hard disk, even if you pay for a company for that.
 3. don't use the hardisk, the more u use the hard disk the more ur data will gone forever.